# iOS swift customise camera overlay with review and trimming functions

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to add a review function for my custom camera control panel after user finished recording. User also can trim video during reviewing. I used the UIImagePickerController to capture videos. I have tried to save the NSURL in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo func and used AVPlayerViewController to play the video. However it cannot add trimming function. Is there any way that I can trim video when reviewing it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use AVCaptureSession , you can receive each and every frames for recording thereby you are able to add functionalities like trimming , quality changing , adding filters etc .Refer apple documentation

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/index.html